# Tkinter active state

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What I'm wanting to do is detect if the mouse has moved over an object on the screen and if it has I want to display the data about the object in a separate frame.  No mouse click allowed, only mouse movement, just like activewidth.  I don't see and reference anywhere showing a built in feature that will allow what I'm trying to do.  Am I wrong and if so what have I not seen yet.  Can't research further that which I don't know about.

Edit: I did use the bad word Object when I was referring to drawn shapes on a canvas.  These are lines, aka a mapping program, placed on a canvas.  When I scroll over a line/road I want it pop up the name of the road on a separate frame.  When I scroll over the symbol for a business I want it to bring up the name of the business and other pertinent information in the separate frame.  Hence why I said activewidth is what I'm basically trying to mimic as its capturing the mouse location and then automatically recognizing something is on the screen underneath where the mouse pointer is located.  If I could capture that same pointer reference...Right now as I'm editting this I'm thinking I would have to create each line with its own separate reference name...

```
z[0] = self.canvas.create_line()
z[1] = self.canvas.create_line()
z[2] = self.canvas.create_line()
```

etc.  Am I wrong on this thought?  Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: If the object is a tkinter widget then you can bind to "<Motion>"

Comment: I already have the buttons, motion, keys 'bind'ed.  I also have assigned z = canvas.create_line...Is there an easy way to find which object was mouse over. I am talking about having mega number of possible points, not simply four or five points on the screen, but 1000's of potential points given the canvas is scrollable.  Like I said I'm looking for something right along the concept of activewidth,

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events, which will fire whenever the mouse enters or leaves a widget.

### Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Hover over me", 
              width=40, bd=2, relief="groove",
              background="lightblue")
l2 = tk.Label(root)
l1.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)
l2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

def handle_enter(event):
    event.widget.configure(background="pink")
    l2.configure(text="you entered the widget")
def handle_leave(event):
    event.widget.configure(background="lightblue")
    l2.configure(text="")

l1.bind("<Enter>", handle_enter)
l1.bind("<Leave>", handle_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm talking a line or oval drawn on a scrollable canvas, of which there could be hundredds to choose from.  Think a map and I move the mouse over the top of road and I want the road info to come up, or I move over the symbol for a particular service and I want the name of the business and other pertinent information for the business to come up.  There could be hundreds. How do I determine which point was moved over? Would every line/road have to a complete separate assignment when I draw the line?

Comment: You need to clarify in your question that you're asking about items drawn on a canvas.

Comment: I updated the post.  Your answer gives me an idea to try but as I indicate in the edited post it could be a real programming nightmare.  Then again...maybe a bit easier than I'm thinking.  Gonna do some work with this when I get home after while and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a tkinter widget, bind to `"<Motion>"`. It will only trigger when the mouse moves over the object that you bound to (or it's children). The event object will contain information about which object you were over and even the object itself.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(text='Label 1')
        lbl.pack()
        lbl.bind('<Motion>', self.motion_detected)

        lbl = tk.Label(text='Thing B')
        lbl.pack()
        lbl.bind('<Motion>', self.motion_detected)

    def motion_detected(self, event):
        print('motion detected in {} at {},{}'.format(event.widget['text'], event.x, event.y))

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x200')
    win = GUI(root)
    win.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A map drawn from gps coordinates.  Businesses along the road.  When I scroll over the line, of which there are many on the screen I want to tell me which road.  When I scroll over a business I want to tell me the name and other pertinent data.  Do I have to create each road with its own unique identifier or is there anyway of retrieving the road data, not a straight line made up of many different connecting lines.

Comment: So like a Tooltip? [There's a standard python recipe for that.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py) But it sounds like your "objects" are Canvas shapes, in which case they aren't tkinter widgets, so this wouldn't apply.

Comment: Yes, canvas shapes.  Actually, something like this could work but the overhead programming that I'm you would have to do would be enormous.  Like I said I think I would have to z[0]=canvas.create_line, z[1]=canvas, z[2]=canvas,etc for each and every indidual item I draw on screen.  Both you and Bryan's answer hint at that idea.

Answer (score 0):

with the CURRENT tag, you can match the canvas element under the mouse

> CURRENT (or “current”) matches the item under the mouse pointer, if
>   any. This can be used inside mouse event bindings to refer to the item
>   that triggered the callback.

[source](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

so,

first you pass your information through the tags option

```
self.canvas.create_line(.... tags="road1")
```

then you bind to the `<Motion>` event and inside the handler you get the tags of the current ellement

```
ellement_id = canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT)
ellement_tags = canvas.gettags(ellement_id)
```